# how to call jquery's datepicker in angular?

Tags: angular

I have installed jquery and jquery types and also tested the inclusion of jquery, by simply implementing a jquerys click function. The problem is that i am unable to call datepicker function.
 Here is the plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/3meCZf3Myg4VGzKv5x3u?p=preview
 This is how i have called datepicker in my component,

```
ngOnInit() { 
        $(function() {
            (<any>$( ".datepicker" )).datepicker();
        });
        $(".datepicker" ).change(()=>{
            let startDate =  $( "#startdate" ).val();
            let endDate =  $( "#enddate" ).val();        
            this.singleFilmEventFormService.formGroup.patchValue({
                startDate: startDate,
                endDate: endDate            
            });
        });           
    }
```

The angular is complaining that  TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: did you install `jquery` and `@types/jquery`?

Comment: yes. I tried to call jquerys click button click function, it is working.

Comment: here is the code in plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit/3meCZf3Myg4VGzKv5x3u?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

In the top of your component file, with your `import` statements, try adding the following line.

`declare var $: any;`

Should set the `$` as a variable/function/class.

Comment: Is it public on Github? Or can we get a plunkr, or gist?